# Trying to get property 'price_change_percentage_24h' of non-object

Tags: php, json, api

I'm trying to work with an API from coingecko and lets say get the 24 hour percentage value for BTC as a PHP variable on page load. This is the api https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&ids=bitcoin.

my code:

```
$jsonArrayResponse = null;
  try{
    $cURLConnection = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&ids=bitcoin');
    curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $res = curl_exec($cURLConnection);
    curl_close($cURLConnection);

    $jsonArrayResponse = json_decode($res);
  }catch(Exception $ex){
      echo "Api Error: ".$ex->getMessage();
  }
  $btcpricechange = $jsonArrayResponse->price_change_percentage_24h;
```

now the problem is i'm getting this error "Trying to get property 'price_change_percentage_24h' of non-object"
i'm currently using my above code with a coinbase api as well as a cryptocompare api and it works fine. while i have little understanding of how to handle api calls, i don't think i'm doing something wrong.. please help

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use ready library for this. Like this one https://github.com/npabisz/coingecko-api.

Install via composer:

```bash
composer require npabisz/coingecko-api
```

And then get your BTC price change last 24h by:

```php
$client = new \CoinGecko\Client();
        
$data = $client->Coins->Markets->get([
    'ids' => 'bitcoin',
    'vs_currency' => 'usd',
]);

$btcPriceChange = $data[0]['price_change_percentage_24h'] ?? null;
```